# How to read a value from a vector without making a copy?

Tags: c++

I have:

```
class Foo {

std::vector<Thing>things;

void bar();

}
```

I need to modify the Thing's stored in things in bar:

```
void bar(){
     //How do I read a Thing stored in the vector, without making a copy?

    Thing thing = things[0]; // Doesn't this make a copy ?

    //.....
}
```

How do I read a Thing stored in the vector, without making a copy? If I do:

```
Thing &thing = things[0];
```

the members of thing are not initialized.

Comment: Why tot simple work on things[0] without storing it in a temp variable?

Comment: Because in actuality, things is a long class name, and has many members within which have many other members within, so each line of code will become very long if I don't learn how to use references.

Comment: What does "the members of thing are not initialized" mean?  `thing` is not a separate object in your last code snippet, so there is nothing to be initialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second snippet is spot-on: the line below does not make a copy.

```
Thing &thing = things[0];
```

Something else is wrong with your code, probably a copy constructor. Since `thing` variable is a reference to the object inside the vector, if you see `thing` partially initialized, the object inside the vector is partially initialized as well.

To fix this problem, make sure that your code has a proper copy constructor, and follows the [*rule of three*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

> But why do I need a copy constructor if I am using a reference?

Since your vector contains objects, not pointers, copy constructor gets invoked when your object is inserted into `vector<Thing>`. If the copy constructor is required because your constructor allocates resources, but is not provided, your object may end up partially initialized when the destructor of the object that has been inserted into the `vector` is invoked.

Comment: But why do I need a copy constructor if I am using a reference ?

Comment: I don't see what the rule of three has to do with this. Thing also just contains vectors of pointers.

Comment: The rule of three states only that if you declare your own constructor, you also have to declare a copy constructor and a destructor, you can't go around that.

Comment: @John "Thing also just contains vectors of pointers." Does `Thing` have a destructor that deletes what's in these pointers?

Comment: no - Thing does not have a destructor or constructor. It doesn't create anything. It is just a convenience class used for storing related things that are created and deleted elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pointers.

```
Thing *thing = &things[0];
thing->pong();
```

If this is not initialized either, your `vector` is not ready.

Comment: If it does not work with a reference, it wouldn't work with a pointer or an iterator either.

Comment: @zenith course. It was another way to verify that something else wasn't wrong in the code. I was unsure about the copy constructor. Personally, I find pointers convenient when dealing with lists of objects. I don't have to care about passing stuff by reference for optimality.

Comment: If you need to do pointer arithmetic then yes, but otherwise pointers just make your code less safe and imply wrong semantics.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iterator`:

```
vector<Thing>::iterator iter = things.begin();
//then use iter as a pointer;
*iter = Thing();
```

Comment: @prakharsingh95 I don't know what exactly you want to tell me, but my code doesn't make any copy of any `Thing`.